# sed и awk one-liner в Perl

Tags: perl, sed, awk

Каким образом я могу вставить

```
sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' input.abc > output.abc
```

и

```
awk -F '|' '{print $1, $NF}'
```

в код скрипта на Perl?

Либо как можно это переписать, чтобы получить в принт нужные данные?

Comment: А какие данные "нужные" ? Сложно сделать скрипт, когда не известно что он должен делать

Comment: Я хочу конвертировать из одного формата в другой. В одном формате каждому виду отведено четыре строчки, каждый новый вид начинается с @. sed выписывает первые две строчки из каждых четырех. Про аналог awk, если я прочитал документ, как я могу полчить в print, допустим, 5 и 7 столбец.

Comment: второй скрипт выводит просто первый столбец строки, которая разделена палочкой. для перла это можно сделать, применив split и взяв нужный элемент массива

Comment: элементарно: [How can I call a shell command in my Perl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3200801/4827341)